# Are items re-rendered when changing and item in ngrx/store

Tags: flux, ngrx

If I have a list of todos bund to an observable and then change one of the todos will all items then be rerendered?

Comment: Without code it's going to be difficult to help you ...

Comment: Even better, if you can post a Plunkr with a demo and I'll definitely be able to tell you :)

Comment: If I had the code then I could see for my self (-: I know that react only draw the new / altered item. But can Angular do the same?

Comment: Yes it can, but once again ... Don't know without code.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular V2 we have 2 types of Components Stateful(Smart) and Statless. Means(Dumb)

Stateful: Are concerned with how things work.

Statless: Are concerned with how things look.

ChangeDetectionStrategy:

When you don't defined any strategy to your component, the ChangeDetection will always "rerun" this component.
In Case of Strategy OnPush he only updates himself if any of inputs changes, but that case only works for Immutables like String, Number not for Objects, or Arrays.

So with ngrx/store and ES6 you can create Immutable Arrays (not the only way)
like

```
case ADD_TODO:
 return [...state, action.payload];
case UPDATE_TODO:
 return state.map(todo => todo.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : todo);
```

Then you will create to components todos and todo

```
<todos [todos]="todosNgRx$ | async"></todos>
```

This component will get the list of todos and re render the second component the Todo.

```
<todo *ngFor="let todo of todos" [todo] = "todo"></todo>
```

This component is dumb, only presents the data.
You need to give ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush so only updates in case of a todo is updated. And if you add a new todo the ngFor will an new component Todo and the rest of the list will not be updated.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I found a todo plunker created with angular 2 and ngrx/store.
It's easy to see in your webbrowsers devtools that only altered items get rendered. So in that regard angular and react are the same.

"plnkr.co/edit/Hb4pJP3jGtOp6b7JubzS?p=preview"